# How does one edit a document's fields in Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have question about editing an entry that has already been index by Lucene. I am a creating a repository of information articles and the entry process requires that classfication be added manually to ease subsequent searching. If a mistake is made I would like to have the ability to change a field without having to do a delete and re-add.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: delete it and insert new one, it's pretty simple :)

Answer (score 2):

No. Even the Lucene 4's new update facility actually deletes and re-adds under the covers.